# How to deal with ctime includes within the scope of a class in CPP?

Tags: c++, class, oop, scope, ctime

I want to use `<ctime>` inside the scope of a class in C++. However, whenever I try to compile the following class, I get the error:

```
error: 'time' cannot be used as a function
      time_t now = time(0);
```

I think it may be something related to the fact that I am trying to call that function inside of the `Session` class, because I have managed to call the `time()` function inside the `main()` function.

What am I doing wrong?

`Session.h`

```
#ifndef _SESSION_H_
#define _SESSION_H_
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

class Session
{
private:
  std::string language;
  time_t date;
  time_t time;

public:
  Session(std::string language, time_t date = NULL, time_t time = NULL);
  ~Session();
};
#endif
```

`Session.cpp`

```
#include <ctime>
#include "Session.h"

Session::Session(std::string language, time_t date, time_t time) : language{language}, date{date}, time{time}
{
  if (date == NULL)
  {
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
  }
}

Session::~Session() {}
```

Comment: Don't do `using namespace std;` and use `std::time()` when calling the function instead. You can probably do even better by using [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: You have **three** different things called `time` in your code: A member variable, an argument to the constructor and a standard library function. How do you expect the compiler to work out which is which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared a constructor parameter with the same name `time` as the function name:

```
Session::Session(std::string language, time_t date, time_t time)
                                                           ^
```

Within the constructor block scope, the parameter hides the function with the same name (and also the data member with the same name declared in the class definition).

So, use the qualified name for the function:

```
time_t now = ::time(0);
```

To access the data member, use an expression with the pointer `this`, like `this->time`.

Comment: Thank you, man... I am sorry if my mistake is so beginerish... I am just a new beginner in C++

Comment: @Breno I am sorry. See my updated answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This requires the `time` function to actually be defined in the global namespace, doesn't it? If it had been defined in `std` only, it wouldn't work (even with `using namespace std;`),  right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo As far as I know the Standard places standard C declarations also in the global namespace.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh, is that so? I thought that was implementation specific. Ok, thanks.